# Are water spirit users ever seen?

Tags: kaze-no-stigma

In *Kaze no Stigma*, fire, earth, and air spirit users are clearly seen using their abilities. Ayano is a fire-user, Kazuma is an air-user, and the Tsuwabuki family are earth users. Water users are never even shown.

Are they ever mentioned as existing, and is there any reason given, even in-universe or by an author, for them to never be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling for 水術師 (water technique users) proved that **they exist** in-universe, but don't seem to appear in both anime & manga. There are **2 named users**:

1. (spoiler for **Light Novel vol. 6**, which is *just after the end of the anime which covers the first 5 volumes*)

   > [クリスティアン・ローエングラム (Kristian Lohengramm)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A2%A8%E3%81%AE%E8%81%96%E7%97%95#%E7%B2%BE%E9%9C%8A%E5%96%B0%E3%81%84)

   who is

   > one of the major antagonists known as Spirit Eater. Having silver hair and amber eyes. Possessing a water divine weapon called 水霊 (*mizuchi*) that has a form of whip/rapier. Able to blast a giant water ball from above his head.
2. (spoiler for [*Kaze no Stigma RPG*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaze_no_Stigma#Role-playing_game), a spin-off gamebook guide for table talk RPG)

   > [ラーン (Lahn?)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A2%A8%E3%81%AE%E8%81%96%E7%97%95#%E6%95%B5%E5%AF%BE%E9%96%A2%E4%BF%82)

   who appears in [***Kaze no Stigma RPG: Shin'en no Suiryuu (Deep Water Dragons)***](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/89872/kaze-no-stigma-rpg-rpg-deep-water-dragons), a replay/add-on gamebook, who is

   > also the main antagonist. A middle-aged man wearing a black robe. Able to create a wall of water to protect himself and calling a water spirit beast [Kelpie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelpie) to attack.

Aside from both of them, **a water technique user is one of the [playable tribe classes](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A2%A8%E3%81%AE%E8%81%96%E7%97%95RPG#%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%A9%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9) in *Kaze no Stigma RPG*** alongside with fire, earth, wind, and irregular.

---

Source: Japanese Wikipedia

- [*Kaze no Stigma*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A2%A8%E3%81%AE%E8%81%96%E7%97%95)
- [*Kaze no Stigma RPG*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A2%A8%E3%81%AE%E8%81%96%E7%97%95RPG)

Answer (score 4):

Since the writer is dead, the story won't continue on from the point where it prematurely ended, but I think it's very likely that the arcs that would've followed (chasing down Rhodes and Lapis/Tsui-Ling) the ending would feature Water mages sooner or later, otherwise mentioning it to begin with would've been pointless.

Answer (score -3):

They were simply hidden by the mist in that show.  They were there the entire time watching if you cared to watch.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Please extend your answer to add more details and provide sources for your claims.